# Cannot convert from 'System.Type' to myself defined interface

Tags: c#, generics, types, constraints, typeconverter

I  defined my own `IExportable` interface, and use it as

```
public static A SomeAction<B>(IList<T> data) where T : IExportable
{
    var tType = typeof(T);
    IList<B> BLists = SomeMethod(tType);
    //...
}
```

that `SomeMethod` is:

```
List<B> SomeMethod(IExportable exportData)
{
   // do somethings
}
```

but when i run my application get this error:

**The best overloaded method match for SomeMethod(IExportable)has some invalid arguments
cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'IFileExport'**
where is my mistake?

Comment: typeof(T) returns instanse of System.Type, but your method take IExportable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof(T)` returns a [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) object that has meta information about the class that is represented by `T`.  `SomeMethod` is looking for an object that extends `IExportable`, so you probably want to create an object that is a `T` which extends `IExportable`.  You have a few options to do this.  The most straight forward option may be to add the `new` constraint on your generic paramter and use `T`'s default constructor.

```
//Notice that I've added the generic paramters A and T.  It looks like you may 
//have missed adding those parameters or you have specified too many types.
public static A SomeAction<A, B, T>(IList<T> data) where T : IExportable, new()
{
    T tType = new T();
    IList<B> BLists = SomeMethod(tType);
    //...
}
```

I've explicitly stated the type of `tType` to better illustrate what's going on in your code:

```
public static A SomeAction<B>(IList<T> data) where T : IExportable
{
    //Notice what typeof returns.
    System.Type tType = typeof(T);
    IList<B> BLists = SomeMethod(tType);
    //...
}
```